# Issues with Python dictionary functions - adding and deleting

Tags: python, whitespace

**UPDATE BELOW**

I'm in an intro to programming class on Zybooks.  I'm on the final project for this chapter and the output keeps failing due to spacing or return issues.  I keep adjusting it and trying to change things but it always ends up failing.  Would  anyone be willing to look at this and give me a hint on where i'm failing?  I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

Here are the steps for the problem:

> 1. Prompt the user to input five pairs of numbers: A player's jersey number (0 - 99) and the player's rating (1 - 9). Store the jersey
>      numbers and the ratings in a dictionary. Output the dictionary's
>      elements with the jersey numbers in ascending order (i.e., output the
>      roster from smallest to largest jersey number). Hint: Dictionary keys
>      can be stored in a sorted list. (3 pts)
> 2. Implement a menu of options for a user to modify the roster. Each option is represented by a single character. The program initially
>      outputs the menu, and outputs the menu after a user chooses an option.
>      The program ends when the user chooses the option to Quit. For this
>      step, the other options do nothing. (2 pts)
> 3. Implement the "Output roster" menu option. (1 pt)
> 4. Implement the "Add player" menu option. Prompt the user for a new player's jersey number and rating. Append the values to the two
>      vectors. (1 pt)
> 5. Implement the "Delete player" menu option. Prompt the user for a player's jersey number. Remove the player from the roster (delete the
>      jersey number and rating). (1 pt)
> 6. Implement the "Update player rating" menu option. Prompt the user for a player's jersey number. Prompt again for a new rating for the
>      player, and then change that player's rating. (1 pt)
> 7. Implement the "Output players above a rating" menu option. Prompt the user for a rating. Print the jersey number and rating for all
>      players with ratings above the entered value. (2 pts)

My code:

```
d={}
for i in range(5):
    jersey=int(input("Enter player %s's jersey number:\n" % str(i+1)))
    rating=int(input("Enter player %s's rating:\n" % str(i+1)))

    if jersey not in d:
        d[jersey]=rating
    print()

print("ROSTER")
for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
    print("Jersey number: %d, Rating: %d" % (k,v))



while True:
    print('\nMENU')
    print('a - Add player')
    print('d - Remove player')
    print('u - Update player rating')
    print('r - Output players above a rating')
    print('o - Output roster')
    print('q - Quit\n')

    choice=input('Choose an option:\n')





    choice=choice.lower()


    if choice=='o':
        print("ROSTER")
        for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
            print("Jersey number:%d,Rating:%d" % (k,v))

    elif choice=='a':

        jersey=int(input("Enter a new player jersey number:\n"))
        rating=int(input("Enter player's rating:\n"))

        if jersey not in d:
            d[jersey]=rating
        else:
            print("\nThe Player already in the list")

    elif choice== 'd':

        jersey=int(input("\nEnter a jersey number:\n"))

        if jersey in d:
            del d[jersey]
        else:
            print("\nThe Player is not in the list")

    elif choice== 'u':

        jersey=int(input("\nEnter a jersey number:\n"))

        if jersey in d:
            rating=int(input("\nEnter a new rating for the player:\n"))
            d[jersey]=rating
        else:
            print("\nThe Player is not in the list")

    elif choice== 'r':


        rating=int(input("\nEnter a rating:\n"))

        for k,v in sorted(d.items()):

            if v > rating:
                print("Jersey number:%d,Rating:%d" % (k,v))

    elif choice=='q':
        break
```

This is the result I'm getting.

[image]

This is the result they want:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I ended up changing the entire lower section of the code.  That solved the returns problem I was having but Now i'm running into something else.  Two functions of the menu are to add and delete entries to the dictionary.  I went back over the lesson and I think they're coded right but they're not functioning.  Can any one point me to where I'm going wrong?  Thanks!

Here is the code (just the lower half, top half is the same):

```
def print_menu():
   menuOp = """MENU
a - Add player
d - Remove player
u - Update player rating
r - Output players above a rating
o - Output roster
q - Quit

Choose an option:"""
   return menuOp

def main():
    while(True):
        c = input()
        if(c=='a'):
            jersey=int(input("Enter a new player jersey number:\n"))
            rating=int(input("Enter player''s rating:\n"))

            if jersey not in d:
                d[jersey]=rating
            else:
                print("\nThe Player already in the list")
        elif(c=='o'):
            print("ROSTER")
            for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
                print("Jersey number:%d,Rating:%d" % (k,v))       
        elif(c=='d'):
            jersey=int(input("\nEnter a jersey number:\n"))

            if jersey in d:
                del d[jersey]
            else:
                print("\nThe Player is not in the list")
        elif(c=='u'):
            jersey=int(input("\nEnter a jersey number:\n"))

            if jersey in d:
                rating=int(input("\nEnter a new rating for the player:\n"))
                d[jersey]=rating
            else:
                print("\nThe Player is not in the list")            
        elif(c=='r'):
            rating=int(input("\nEnter a rating:\n"))

            for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
                if v > rating:
                    print("Jersey number:%d,Rating:%d" % (k,v))
        elif(c=='q'):
            print()
            break
print()
print(print_menu())
```

This is my current output:
[image]

This is the output they want.  You can see that there should be an extra entry.
[image]

Sorry, dont know why the paste formatting got weird.

Comment: If I run your code, everything works perfectly fine... I get the exact output you want, and am able to navigate through your menu! Maybe it is a problem with the environment you are programming in. I for one, am not able to reproduce your problem and everything works fine..

Comment: Thanks for looking at it @Psychotechnopath.  The problem is that this is a Zybook course.  So their interpreter is different I guess.  I was running it in a different environment and not getting the errors too.  I'm just not sure how to fix this to make it work in Zybooks.

Comment: I am guessing that the zybooks interpreter is treating a `\n` in single quotes differently than when it's in double quotes. That is, in single quotes it renders a `\n` as the return character and in double quotes it actually renders a new line.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Jack.  I tried making that change but it didnt end up helping since I'd already changed the code.  But i believe you are right, i think I made that error on some previous task and that fixed it.